# RSpec report failure outside tests to JUnit

Tags: junit, rspec

How do I configure rspec to report the absence of examples as a failure in the JUnit report?

To give you some context: I recently parallelized my `rspec` test suite using [`parallel_rspec`](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests). Doing so, I forgot to migrate a `--require XYZ` from the `.rspec` file to `.rspec_parallel`. As most of my specs started with `require 'XYZ'` on their own, I didn't notice the error right away. If one of the runners starts with a spec that does not have that include, it fails for some symbols not being defined ([see here](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/issues/644)). However, the generated JUnit reports just state that there was no test being executed so that failing workers went unnoticed in our Jenkins.

I am quite certain that the lacking `--require` flag was breaking the runner, but I would like to catch if that should not have been the single cause. Therefore, how would I configure rspec to report "no tests" as a failure when using `--format RspecJunitFormatter --out tmp/rspec.xml`?

```
$ rspec --version
RSpec 3.7
  - rspec-core 3.7.1
  - rspec-expectations 3.7.0
  - rspec-mocks 3.7.0
  - rspec-support 3.7.1
```